# How can I get requests to output plain HTML?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have a simple piece of code that was working perfectly fine for years with Python2.7 but when I changed to Python3.7, it screwed up.

Here's the pertinent code...

```
result = requests.get(url,headers=headers1,proxies={ 'https': 'https://' + ip + ':80' })
print("Content-type: text/plain\n")
print(result.content)
```

And here's part of the output when using 2.7...

```
local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OX-hpKKSTj5PW.woff2) format('woff2'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OXOhv.woff) format('woff');
unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
```

In 2.7 it just prints the html code to the page, which is what I need. In 3.7 it's printing out bytes, inserting \n and escaping parts of the code. I've been trying various things for hours but nothing seems to work.

```
local(\'OpenSans-Light\'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OXehpKKSTj5PW.woff2) format(\'woff2\'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem5YaGs126MiZpBA-UN_r8OXOhv.woff) format(\'woff\');\n    unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;\n}\n/* latin-ext */\n@font-face {\n    font-family: \'Open Sans\';\n    font-style: normal;\n    font-display: fallback;\n    font-weight: 300;\n    src: local(\'Open Sans Light\'), local(\'OpenSans-Light\'),
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Steve

UPDATE: For now I've just specified that the script should use 2.7 for this script, and it works fine. I'd still like to figure out why 3.7 doesn't output plain html code to the page, so hoping somebody has a solution.

Comment: Have you tried `print(result.text)` instead of `print(result.content)`?

Comment: I tried that and get an error - UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xa0' in position 1209: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Could you `print(result.encoding)` and let me know what is is?

Comment: It's utf-8 and calling print(result.text) throws the error above, which makes sense.

Comment: ```result.content.decode('utf-8')``` sometimes does the trick for me

Comment: That led me in the right direction. print(result.content.decode('ascii', 'ignore')) is the solution I was looking for. Thanks!